# Three parameter in Post method using nsurlconnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post, nsurlconnection, url-parameters

I am new to IOS i need to pass three parameter in POST method.my parameter are (1)str (2)str1 (3)str2.this three parameter are fetch from different url in string format.

coding for POST method:
  i need to add these parameter in method?i already added str parameter but i am struggling to pass other two(str1,str2) parameter.

```
-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method params:(NSString *)str{

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"branch_id=%@",str];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ){

        mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
```

Viewdidload:
here also i want to str1 and str2 parameter.

```
[self sendDataToServer :@"POST" params:str];
```

Comment: why don't you use array?

Comment: three parameter are taken from different url so i convert into different string if its possible to convert into array?@TysonVignesh

Comment: where you called this method, [self sendDataToServer :@"POST" params:str];

Comment: if you show that it is easy to modify

Comment: viewdidload @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement in multiple ways

**Choice-1**

```
-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method firstparams:(NSString *)firststr secondparam:(NSString *)secondstr thirdparam:(NSString *)thirdstr{

 NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"branch_id=%@&xxxx=%@&yyyyy=%@",firststr,secondstr,thirdstr];

// continue your works as its same flow
```

call method like

```
[self sendDataToServer :@"POST" firstparams:@"yourbranchID" secondparam:@"xxxValue" thirdparam:@"yyyyvalue"];
```

**Choice-2**

what ever you did is correct, just modify some code in viewdidload or else

```
  // add all values in one string using  stringWithFormat
  NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"branch_id=%@&xxxx=%@&yyyyy=%@",firststr,secondstr,thirdstr];
// and pass the param to web call
[self sendDataToServer :@"POST" params:str];
```

**call method as**

```
-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method params:(NSString *)str{
// no need of this line
// NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"branch_id=%@",str];

// directly called the str in her
NSData *postData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

 /.... as its is continue the same work
```

Comment: negative voters can explain once what mistake you found here

Comment: still no change parameter not passing and not getting any response @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: can you update code once with viewdidload code also,

Comment: ya i change in viewdidload also@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @A.sonu - I am waiting for your resposne

Comment: for your choice1 and choice 2 coding both i tried but it cannot showing any response@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111372/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-a-sonu).

Answer (score -1):

instead of passing it as NSString just add the three string in a globally declared array and add objects to it and send it to web service.
or create them as NSDictionary and convert them as json string to web service.

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"param1": str1, @"param2": str2, @"param3": str3 };
[self sendDataToServer :@"POST" params:params];

-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method params:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                         error:&error];

    if (! jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];


        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:jsonString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        if( theConnection ){

            mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please give any detail coding i am new to ios @Tyson Vignesh

Comment: it depends upon the web service developer to say it as a single string or a json string

Comment: did you check my updated answer or just other answers or enough for you? @A.sonu